# Control a 2D printer like a 3D printer

Tags: 2d

Probably barely on-topic, but I'm wondering if there's any way to control a 2D inkjet/laser printer similar to 3D printer. Specifically:

- Shifting the XY axis by a certain amount
- Controlling the paper feeder by small increments
- Dispelling ink at defined amounts

2D printers have a very high resolution and can be useful for some things, which is why I'm asking.

Comment: Do you imply to fit it with a controller board other than the circuit board that is in the printer already? Or do you want to control the printer through the original circuit board?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, modern printers take in documents in some form and print from there. As a 3D printing analogy, the "slicing" is done on the printer, not the computer.

Comment: I think that there are options for using a new controller board integrated with the 2D printer that would best answer this question. I found some YouTube videos of people selling homemade boxes with custom controllers (for too much money). But I don't know what they are or how to make them

Answer (score 1):

### No

- Most 2D printers use very different motor setups - 3D Printers use steppers, Paper printers usually use simple motors and encoders.
- Printers take input in special data formats. These can be pretty much normal Text files of what characters to print but a print job sent from the printer driver also contains specific orders and might not even be readable to humans. This file of instructions and pattern to print then is *processed* into the actual movement of the printhead and paper only in the printer itself.
- 2D Printer software is super locked down. You can only get the firmware of a paper printer in formats that are absolutely nonreadable. Compare how hard it was for [Itkin and Balmas to reverse engineer just the fax protocol of modern printers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qLCE8spVX9Q). Then, amplify that by a few notches because the fax protocol has a known standard it needs to uphold but the printer itself does not.